# Python: sorted insert into list

Tags: python

This is a common task when building a list incrementally: having sorted the container, subsequent inserts should inject values efficiently at the correct location such that the sorted container stays sorted, and an iterator **readout** onto a standard list is O(n), being perfectly clear: I am looking for a call to compiled O(logn) inserts into what amounts to a list, as I would expect in the ordered set I'd get from `std::set` (where I'd have to explicitly specify `std::unordered_set` to get the default python behavior).

OrderedSet (the missing python type) would accomplish this task.  Is there a way to get this 
effect in python such that it is as efficient *within the container* as it would be expected to be in a general purpose compiled language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bisect
mylist = [1,2,5]
bisect.insort(mylist,4)
print(mylist)
# [1, 2, 4, 5]
```